# Black diamonds with question marks instead of pound sign causing issues

Tags: html

have a site that pulls in data from a MS SQL database and in there the user inputs the price of the property (i.e. £159,950) and on the desktop site this pulls in fine but they have a dedicated mobile site (their choice, going responsive on next re-design) and the pound sign won't pull in, instead it shows the black diamond with a question mark in it. The bizarre thing is though, if I refresh the page the pound sign appears fine so really baffled by it to be honest. When I view the mobile URL in a desktop browser the £ sign shows fine also. Really annoying me now. I have the following in the header:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//WAPFORUM//DTD XHTML Mobile 1.0//EN" "http://www.wapforum.org/DTD/xhtml-mobile10.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
```

and have tried alternatives but to no avail yet. Any ideas? Seems odd that once you refresh it works. You would think it would or it wouldn't. Thank you for any advice.

Comment: Where is the £ being displayed as the black diamond? In the URL? In the input?

Comment: It comes in on the page itself.

Answer (score 1):

Check what your server is sending in the HTTP headers. It should be configured to send a `charset:` header (with the correct value) instead of relying on meta tags in the page code.

NOTE that in this day and age, using any charset other than `utf-8` is asking for trouble (makes the site incompatible with any language other than the one for which your specific charset is suited, creates problems with user input when they type anything other than base ASCII characters, prevents using a multitude of useful characters such as emoji, etc.). Consider switching to utf-8 for the entire site.

Comment: Thanks for that, I have that one all other pages of the site but the £ sign isn’t a characheter of utf-8 so have to use iso-8559-1

Comment: The £ sign definitely *is* in the utf-8 character set - as is pretty much every character in most languages in the world. The utf-8 equivalent is the sequence 0xC2 0xA3, which is the 163rd character in the Unicode set, or "&#163;" as noted in another answer.

Comment: If I use

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

the price shows as: �155,995 on desktop and mobile version. Change it to 

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">

and it shows as £155,995 on desktop and on mobile it shows the diamond until I refresh then it shows the £ sign so that is what I always use the latter. The data is in a MS SQL server database not MySQL so may make a difference?

Comment: The data that's already in the database will be whatever was written there, changing the charset on the page won't update the database.If the database has records with '£' encoded in iso-8559-1, they won't show correctly when interpreted as a utf-8 character.  New entries however will get written properly.  BTW: some databases are in the habit of translating strings between character sets, e.g., if the SQL client has a charset different from the one declared for the table (or the column), it will get translated. Then if you change the SQL client config, it will get a different translation.

Comment: Yes, charset in HTTP response Content-Type overrides HTML meta charset.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing all occurrences of `£` with its [HTML entity](https://www.freeformatter.com/html-entities.html), `&#163;`.

Comment: Thanks but client enters the price in a database as £195,950 so the page just pulls in whatever they put in. Unless there is an option to rewrite any £ sign to that via some coding? Just bizarre why it works when refreshing.

Comment: You could replace them with a regex: `price.replace(/£/g, "&#163;")`. And yeah, it's weird how it works when you refresh.

Comment: Thanks for that, how do I add that to the page, never used one before, sorry. Wrapped in a script file?

Comment: You'd do it where your database returns the information. Depending on what back-end language your site uses, the replace method would differ.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up using this to fix it by replacing the £ sign with the correct HTML code for it.

```
<%
sValue = rs.Fields.Item("displayedprice").Value
sValue = replace(sValue, "£","&#163;")
%>

<h3><span class="price"><%=sValue%></span></h3>
```

Thanks for those that offered help, much appreciated.